# Node.js mssql Global connection already exists connection pool memory leak

Tags: sql, sql-server, node.js

New to Node. I have looked at some other questions, and haven't found a direct answer. I'm creating a module for a simple Sql data call, but am getting the "Global connection already exists" error. I believe my solution lies in using a connectionPool, but I am uncertain of how to create a connection pool or if I'm doing it correctly. Any help is appreciated. I have removed any sensitive login data as well.

**UPDATE:** by switching my sql.close() and putting it before my onDone&&onDone() callback function, I now am receiving the correct data, but node is now giving warnings of " Warning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 error listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit"

What's not working: I can successfully run my first call, but then every call after that returns nothing. I have verified using SQL profiler that only one call is being made to the server. So I believe something in my code is bypassing the second call and returning a null result set?

```
const self = {};
// NPM package that supports accessing Microsoft SQL databases from node.
let sql = require('mssql');
let debug = false;
let connection;
// configure SQL Connection. The credentials below should be handled more securely. 
// While this backend code is not accessible via public web accesses, it will be in
// GitHub.
let config = {
    domain:   "hidden",
    user:     "hidden",
    password: 'hidden',
    server:   'hidden', 
    database: 'hidden',

    options: {
        encrypt: false // Use this if you're on Windows Azure 
    }
};

self.getSQLData = function getSQLData (sprocInfo,onDone,onRow) {
    // Connect to SQL Server.
    if(debug) console.log("Hit SQL Function \n");
    if (typeof(sprocInfo.parameters) === 'object' && Array.isArray(sprocInfo.parameters)){
        if(debug)console.log("Passed array check");

        if(sprocInfo.database) config.database = sprocInfo.database;

        if(connection && connection._connected){
            if(debug) console.log("Inside SQL Connection");
            const request = new sql.Request(connection); //create a new request
            request.stream = true;
            var results = [];
            //put all parameters as input parameters to sql call
            sprocInfo.parameters.forEach(function(element){
                request.input(element.parameterName.toString(),sql.NVarChar,element.parameterValue);
                //NEED to remove hard typing of Integers. Maybe case statement based on typeof??
            });

            request.on('row', row => {
                results.push(row);
                onRow && onRow(row);
            });

            request.on('done', result => {
                // console.log("Result in request.on done"+JSON.stringify(result));
                onDone && onDone(results);
                sql.close();
            });

            request.on('error', err => {
                // May be emitted multiple times
                if ( debug ) console.log('error');
                if ( debug ) console.log('the error is: ' + err);
            });

            request.execute(sprocInfo.procedure)
        } else {
            connection = sql.connect(config, err => {
                if(debug) console.log("Inside SQL Connection");
                const request = new sql.Request(); //create a new request
                request.stream = true;
                var results = [];
                //put all parameters as input parameters to sql call
                sprocInfo.parameters.forEach(function(element){
                    request.input(element.parameterName.toString(),sql.NVarChar,element.parameterValue);
                    //NEED to remove hard typing of Integers. Maybe case statement based on typeof??
                });

                request.on('row', row => {
                    results.push(row);
                    onRow && onRow(row);
                });

                request.on('done', result => {
                    // console.log("Result in request.on done"+JSON.stringify(result));
                    onDone && onDone(results);
                    sql.close();
                });

                request.on('error', err => {
                    // May be emitted multiple times
                    if ( debug ) console.log('error');
                    if ( debug ) console.log('the error is: ' + err);
                });

                request.execute(sprocInfo.procedure)

            });
        }


        sql.on('error', err => {
            console.log("Error: Failed to connect to SQL Server");
        });

    } else {
        throw new Error ("Parameters is not an array");
    }
};

module.exports = self;
```